# Why won't my JButton add the JPanel from a separate class?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to add another `JPanel` from another class into my main `JPanel`. A random number is generated and if it is a certain value it will import a new Panel with movie info into my main Panel to be displayed. I am not sure why my panel is not showing when I click my button.

```
public class NetflixFrame extends JFrame {

public JButton button;

public NetflixFrame() {
    super ("App");

    MovieSuggestion port = new MovieSuggestion();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(800,800));

    button = new JButton("Start");

    JPanel primary = new JPanel();
    primary.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
    primary.add(button);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int score1 = (int )(Math.random() * 11 + 1);

            if(score1<=10) {
                port.Panel1();
            }
        }
    });

    add(primary);
    setVisible(true);
}
  }
```

Panel to be added:

```
public class MovieSuggestion extends JFrame{

public static Component Panel1() {

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("./src/Hook.jpg");

    JPanel first = new JPanel();
    first.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,200));
    first.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel("Favorite Movie:", image, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    imageLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    imageLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
    imageLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    first.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    return first;

}
```

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently...

Comment: ..  4) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 5) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 6) `new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20)` Use `Font.SERIF` instead of `"Times New Roman"` for x-plat.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `port.Panel1()` which returns a `JPanel`, but you are not doing anything with it.

If you want display it into your main `JPanel`, then you need to add the returned `JPanel` to the main `JPanel`.

Put this inside your `if` statement: `primary.add(port.Panel1());`

Comment: I've done this and it is still not doing anything when the button is pressed

Comment: @Jibblz Try setting a position for the `JPanel` using the layout manager.

Comment: still nothing, unfortunately